# ¿Cómo puedo aumentar el valor de un número en un String?

Tags: php

Lo que busco hacer es aumentar el valor de un número en un `string`.

Por ejemplo teniendo un `string` como este:

```
$string = "Hola = 1"
```

Y yo quiero sumarle `2` al número `1` del `string` cada vez que abra el archivo php.

```
$valor = 2;
$string = "Hola = 1";
$final = $string + $valor;
echo $final;
//Salida: Hola = 3
```

¿Cómo podría hacer esto?

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Aumentar Valor</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="./aumentar.php">
<button type="submit" name="aumentar" value="1">
<button type="submit" name="aumentar" value="2">
<button type="submit" name="aumentar" value="3">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
include "connect-database.php";
$valor = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['aumentar']);
$archivo = fopen("numero.txt", "r");
$string = fread($archivo);
fclose($archivo);
$final = $string + $valor;
$archivo = fopen("numero.txt", "w");
$string = fwrite($archivo, $final);
fclose($archivo);
echo $final;
exit();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guarda el `$string` sin el número por un lado. Y guarda el `$valor` como string también. 
Y concatenas los dos strings en cuestión después.

```
$valor = "2";
$string = "Hola = ";
$final = $string + $valor;
echo $final;
```

Si necesitases modificar la variable `$valor` como entero/int, puedes convertirla a int y después a string de nuevo:

```
int($valor);
ToString($valor);
```

Comment: Por qué "si o si la variable tiene que estar $string"? No das muchas explicaciones y la solución que te acaban de dar es lo que necesitas, al menos en el planteamiento original de tu problema.

Comment: @RichardHasgton Con `substr()` vas a tener que controlar más cosas. Ya que el número puede ser de varios dígitos.

Comment: @Flowen Ya Lo Hice Yo Pero Igual Gracias Por Tu Respuesta, Me Base En Tu Respuesta Para Hacerlo :)

Answer (score 0):

buenos dias solo tiene que implementa el operado incrementado

https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.operators.increment.php

```
<?php
$string = "Hola = 1";
$string++;
$string++;
echo $string;  //Hola = 3
?>
```